# Password for the System Center 2012 R2 Orchestrator Evaluation VHD

Tags: system-center

I recently downloaded the Evaluation VHD for System Center 2012 R2 Orchestrator. After performing the initial setup, I am unable to log in with the credentials that i had provided initially for the Administrator. I faced a similar situation while working with Evaluation VHD for System Center 2012 R2 App Controller. In that case, after some searches I found 'R2Preview!' as its default password.
I have already tried other passwords :

- P@ssword1
- P@ssword
- p@ssword1
- password1
- blank password.

Answer (score 0):

Password1

found it on some forum. Searched through the documentation but couldn't find any record also.